# Cannot run js script after fetch it (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, promise, fetch

Hello I've got a problem with fetch data in my javascript. I want to fetch api but everytime when I want to do this, somethink goes wrong. First I want to fetch html template, and this is working fine but when I want to use JS script from this file then it shows that 'function is not defined' I was trying many ways to do that. Below is code what doesn't work

```
var dataset; 
fetch('../templates/mainPage.html') 
    .then(response => response.text()) 
    .then(data => {
    dataset = data;
    document.getElementById('mainContent').innerHTML = dataset;
    //var script = document.createElement('script');
    //script.src = '../js/mainTmpl.js';
    
    //document.body.appendChild(script);
    //document.body.innerHTML += '<script defer src="../js/mainTmpl.js"></script>';
    //script.addEventListener('load', logDataset);
    
    logDataset();
});
```

and below is template what I want to use (HTML template and JS script is added to main HTML but that show me 'logDataset is not defined'

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main-container">
        <span class="main-text" id="main-text">{{TEST}}</span>
        <div class="blue-line"></div>
        <span class="sub-text" id='sub-text'></span>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
window.logDataset = function () {
var thathref = window.location.pathname;
document.getElementById('mainContent').innerHTML = dataset; 
var mainText = document.getElementById('main-text');
var subtext = document.getElementById('sub-text');
console.log('test');
fetch('http://localhost:8080/'+thathref).then(
function(u){ return u.json(); }
).then(function(data){
        var data1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        mainText.innerHTML = data1[0].text;
        subtext.innerHTML = data1[1].text;
        console.log(data1[0].text);
    }
);
```

}

I've comment different methods that I tried to have working fine but it's still bad (I have to have JS script in other files)

Below screen of error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGCM7.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewoIk.png)

Comment: Read the error, it is saying a variable is not defined.

Comment: Yeah I know but it's defined in second file and I assigned this second file to the first file

Comment: They will execute in order. No hoisting. If one file depends on other, you must put it after the one it needs

Comment: Ok, Can you show me some example? I really care about this. Do I have to put something more in second file? checking if it is loaded or what?

Comment: Do not call any function in your (declarations) files, make one last file where you will put the call to the declared functions

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1clyno?file=index.html

12345678901236789012345678901

Comment: It' will not work like that, cuz I have here 1 file in stackblitz, I want 1 file html with different template js and html. Load them and run

Comment: Please post the complete code url and adjust the format.
What does each file have, and what effect does it have to run in the end?

Comment: Only the above part, it is difficult to understand the effect you want

Comment: Ok I've got the solution, It was problem because I didn't resolve promise and that's why I couldn't run any script